# Why is float4 expected to out perform float in a prefix sum

Tags: performance, opencl, gpu

In OpenCL in Action, Matthew Scarpino comments that switching his prefix-sum from a 32bit float to a 128bit collection of 4 floats results in a significant performance improvement, almost 4 times faster!

> When you run the Ch10/reduction application, it will execute both the
> reduction_scalar and reduction_vector kernels. In addition to checking
> the results, it measures the time taken for each kernel to execute. On
> my system, the results are as follows:
>
> reduction_scalar: Check passed. Total time = 489031
>
> reduction_vector: Check passed. Total time = 136157

[image: Matthew Scarpino]

A similar claim is made by GPU Gems, citing what appears to be a course project from a class, that is no longer available.

> We employ a technique suggested by David Lichterman, which processes
> eight elements per thread instead of two by loading two
> float4 elements per thread rather than two float
> elements (Lichterman 2007).

[Parallel Prefix Sum (Scan) with CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html)

One explanation is that memory requests per threads go up, but this doesn't make sense to me as I expect the same total number of memory requests are issued, perhaps resulting in the same overall performance.

Alternatively, each warp issues a request, and then goes to sleep. In the `float4` case it wakes up with 4 times more data, but in the `float` case the data isn't cached so subsequent threads will also need to go to sleep and wait for new data. On the other hand. I expect the memory to be streamed as the threads inside the warp are awoken.

I'm wondering if some experts can chime in and provide a sequential explanation  explain why `float4` performs significantly faster than `float`, in terms of memory access or computation.

Comment: The idea is I believe that to saturate the memory bandwidth, you need to issue memory requests of the maximum width for your hardware. If you issue individual requests of 1B (char) per work item, and if the requests are "coalesced" the CUDA way with warps of 32 work items, you'll only load 32*1B per clock cycle per SM. If you issue individual requests of 4B (float), you'll load 32*4=256B per cycle per SM. And if you use 256B data (float4), you'll load 1024B per SM per cycle (provided the hw supports it).

Comment: With AMD's older VLIW architecture you needed to use vectors to fully utilize the hardware. Their new GCN hardware is scalar, so this is no longer needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually two things at play here. One is more efficient use of the memory bandwidth, the other is an improved ratio of computations to memory transactions with consequent improved latency hiding.

To clarify the memory bandwidth aspect, consider for example the case of an NVIDIA GPU: the hardware is designed so that it can provide 128 *bytes* (from a 128-byte-aligned segment) in a single transaction to a warp; this is true both for the architectures with an L1 cache (the cacheline being 128 bytes) and in older architectures without cache. Hence, when using `float`s insead of a wider data type you're using at most half of the available bandwidth, for no reason.

So, just switching from `float` to `float2` will more or less double the bandwidth, since the same number of memory transactions will load twice the data. Additionally, for every transaction the work-items will now have twice the data to work on: this makes it easier to hide the latency of the loads (you need half the work-items you needed with just `float`s).

The improvement from `float2` to `float4` is considerably less drastic, but you'll generally still see some. This is due to the fact that GPUs are designed to load 128-bit data for work-items (think about 4 projective coordinates or 4 color components (RGBA)). Hardware-wise, this isn't more efficient than loading 64-bit data (you'll typically need twice the transactions to actually provide `float4`s than you needed to provide `float2`s). *However*, the hardware is designed to enact the load of 128-bit data with a single *instruction* (that results in two transactions behind the scenes). This is more efficient, especially when in a loop, as it results in fewer loop iterations to process the same amount of data (keep in mind that in a loop the next load instruction is dependent on the previous index increase, so you're effectivelly getting rid of a pair of dependent instructions.)

Note that moving on to `float8` or `float16` will *not* improve things further, as the hardware is *not* designed for those data types (on GPU), and in fact those kinds of loads will in general destroy coalescence or worsen cacheline usage, resulting in worse performance.

Comment: >>the hardware is designed so that it can provide 128 bytes


I'm still confused on this point, so every time I ask for 32bits it takes the same time as asking for 128 bits. I want to believe you but can you elaborate on this, maybe a source or something? Also its bits right?

Comment: No, I actually mean _bytes_, and it's bytes and not bits because the hardware acts in terms of warps (or half-warps, depending on the generation).<br>So if each work-item asks for a single 32-bit value (e.g. a `float`) the controller will send 16*32-bit values (one per work-item in a half-warp) in a single transaction, if it can (where “it can” depends again on generation and access pattern, and it's what coalescence is all about). That's 64 _bytes_ in a transaction.

Comment: (continued)<br>If each work-item reads a 64-bit element, the controller will, if possible, serve a full half-warp in a transaction, and that's 128 _bytes_. If each work-item reads a 128-bit element, the controller will, if possible, serve a full half-warp in _two_ transactions.<br>For GPUs with a working cache it's even simpler than that: the L1 cachelines are 128 _bytes_. Again, this is because the hardware is designed to think in terms of warps rather than single work-items.<br>The details for AMD change, but the principles are pretty much the same.

Comment: (continued)#2 As references, you can look these details up in the CUDA C Programming guide (the appendix has detais about the memory behavior for the various generations) and similarly in the AMD APP manuals.